# jquery Mobile - Auto Divider

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquery Mobile AutoDivider for a web project of mine and it works great in IE8, but for some reason in Chrome it's not generating the headers for me.

My question is: How exactly does the AutoDivider determine what to make a 'divider'?  Is is just the first item within your `<li></li>`?

Here's my basic HTML structure (it's ultimately placed in a ASP.Net Repeater:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true">
  <li>
      <img src="mySource.jpg" alt="" />
        <h3><a href="#">John Doe</a></h3>
           <p><strong>Company Name Here</strong></p>
           <p>User Address</p>
           <p class="ui-li-aside">
             <strong style="display: none;"><!-- This is what seems to make the headers in IE, placing this right here: -->
             Last Name of Employee</strong>
            </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the docu http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

> Autodividers
>
> A listview can be configured to automatically generate dividers for its items. This is
> done by adding a data-autodividers="true" attribute to any listview.
>
> By default, the text used to create dividers is the uppercased first letter of the
> item's text. Alternatively you can specify divider text by setting the > autodividersSelector option on the listview programmatically.